# Custom Text To Autofill Textarea When DropDown Option Selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need some help with the autofill in the textarea when I select the drop down. I tried it and it works perfect on jsfiddle but when I upload the script on my web hosting nothing is happening. I don't know where I am wrong.

```
    <?php

    $subject = $_POST['EmailSubject'];
    $message = $_POST['EmailBody'];

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: SocialDealers <admin@admin.com>' . "\r\n";
    $emailList = explode("\n",$_POST['EmailList']);
    if(count($emailList) > 0){
      foreach($emailList as $to){
        $to = trim($to);
        $sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        if ($sent){
          echo "<p>Sent: $to</p>";
        }
        else{
           echo "<p>Not Sent: $to</p>";
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      echo "<p>No email addresses</p>";
    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    var contentToInsert = 'Hi Amey';
    $( "#listbox" ).change(function() {
        if ($( "#listbox" ).val() == '2') {
            $("#EmailBody").html(contentToInsert);
        } else {
            $("#EmailBody").html("");
        }
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <center>
    <form method="post">
    <br><strong>PHP Email Sender</strong><br><br><br>

    Email List<br>
    <textarea name="EmailList" placeholder="email@email.com (New Email Each Line)"  rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

    Subject<br>
    <input type="text" name="EmailSubject" placeholder="Your Subject Goes Here"><br><br>

    Select Automated HTML Content<br>
    <select id="listbox">
        <option id="option1">Select Offers...</option>
        <option id="option2">1</option>
        <option id="option3">2</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>

    Body<br>
    <textarea name="EmailBody" id="EmailBody" placeholder="Write your content (HTML Accepted)"  rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
    </form><br><br>

    </center>
    </html>
```

I don't know where i missed it but i tried all day to figure out the problem and i am not understanding anything. Also if it would be possible i would want the selection text to be from another text file.

Example:

- The main file name would be mail.php
- Option 1 Select's some text which would be in other file named abctext.txt

Answer (score 0):

If it's working in `Jsfiddle` and not in your hosted environment , then you need to make sure that you referenced the `JQuery` library in your code.
Get the html code of your compiled page and check if there is a reference to the `Jquery JS file`

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is there a reference for jquery library js file

Comment: I just told you yes i tried it and added the reference file from jquery.com to my host. It is still not working. I'm a learner and this seems to be pretty easy. Though you helped me and thanks for that. The difficult part for me would be how would i select a new text file for each content i want for each option?